# Cannot access text mode - black screen

Tags: grub2, nvidia, cuda, text-mode

I am trying to install CUDA and Theano using [this guide](http://spturtle.blogspot.com.au/2015/07/cuda70-and-theano-setup-in-ubuntu-linux.html?showComment=1441943420186):

Before installing CUDA, it is recommended to switch to text mode and kill x server. However, I cannot access text mode, I just have a black screen when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution for me was to use:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And then edit this line to add nomodeset:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```